# Keep logo on the same line as nav

Tags: html, css

I want to have my logo image on my site on the left of my navigation. Can anyone tell me how I should put it into my code without having it force the other items onto a row below:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/gMm2P/11/

I think it is something to do with `in-line block` but im not sure. I'm also not sure if my image should go within the list or if it should be outside it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @NareshRavlani You just linked the same Fiddle as the OP. Oops!

Comment: Not sure, for what you want but yes, you are thinking in right direction. You need to put a logo inside list. It will look like this : http://jsfiddle.net/gMm2P/16/

Comment: @TylerH Made correction :)

Comment: @NareshRavlani Nice; You should include it as an answer.

Comment: @TylerH Surely I can but I dont think SO is all about posting answers.   It will be great if James can solve it himself. I am more than happy to help James getting this done by himself :) And yes if this is what James wanted, then I will post this as an answer so that if other people see this question, they can find solution, too..!

Comment: @NareshRavlani true, but if you post a working solution in a comment, it's not really semantically different from posting it as an answer ;-)

Comment: @TylerH : I just made an edit to answer this concern ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways you can accomplish this:

Add this to your CSS:

```
.logo {
    float: left;
}
```

OR make this addition/change:

```
.logo {
    position: absolute;
}

ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Where `padding-left`'s value is enough pixels so that it pushes the links completely to the right of the logo. It's impossible for me to know the proper value without knowing the width of your logo image.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the logo to the list or float the logo to the left:

```
#header .logo{float:left;}
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this (or why the didn't comment), but it is a working solution, so +1 from me.